2x4 Shed Roof 40 psf snow load
am I ok with 2x4 dimensional lumber to span 7', spaced 12" on center, with a polycarbonate roof and a snow load potential of 40 psf. Standing on edge, so 3.5 inches and metal hangers to hold the ends. Shed would be 7 wide by 8 long. I hope that's enough info! Thanks In advance!

Your roof would just be flat?     I don't see the issue with 2x4s with 12" OC and blocking but I would expect at LEAST a 30% pitch.
